# Identification of butterfly from its caterpillar stage

Tags: species-identification, entomology

Today I visited Bannerghatta national park's butterfly park situated in Bengaluru, Karnataka, India.

I snapped a picture of a caterpillar in butterfly park.

I inquired to caretakers over there for the identification of the caterpillar. However, They were confused and didn't give me any answer.

I tried searching with the google lens application, however, it shows parasitism and not caterpillar identification.

Please help me identify this cute caterpillar.

Below is the picture I took.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Euploea Core](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euploea_core#Caterpillar).

Pupates into common crow butterfly. (Aka. common Indian crow, common Australian crow, [oleander butterfly (link to caterpillar)](https://www.alamy.com/colourful-orange-black-striped-caterpillar-of-oleander-butterfly-euploea-core-corinna-on-stem-of-plant-in-a-garden-on-dark-background-in-australia-image363623658.html?pv=1&stamp=2&imageid=30C206EF-88AA-4172-97B3-F6574EF64A7C&p=174592&n=0&orientation=0&pn=1&searchtype=0&IsFromSearch=1&srch=foo%3Dbar%26st%3D0%26pn%3D1%26ps%3D100%26sortby%3D2%26resultview%3DsortbyPopular%26npgs%3D0%26qt%3Daustralian%2520caterpillars%26qt_raw%3Daustralian%2520caterpillars%26lic%3D3%26mr%3D0%26pr%3D0%26ot%3D0%26creative%3D%26ag%3D0%26hc%3D0%26pc%3D%26blackwhite%3D%26cutout%3D%26tbar%3D1%26et%3D0x000000000000000000000%26vp%3D0%26loc%3D0%26imgt%3D0%26dtfr%3D%26dtto%3D%26size%3D0xFF%26archive%3D1%26groupid%3D%26pseudoid%3D%26a%3D%26cdid%3D%26cdsrt%3D%26name%3D%26qn%3D%26apalib%3D%26apalic%3D%26lightbox%3D%26gname%3D%26gtype%3D%26xstx%3D0%26simid%3D%26saveQry%3D%26editorial%3D1%26nu%3D%26t%3D%26edoptin%3D%26customgeoip%3D%26cap%3D1%26cbstore%3D1%26vd%3D0%26lb%3D%26fi%3D2%26edrf%3D%26ispremium%3D1%26flip%3D0%26pl%3D)).

[A common butterfly](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Common_crow_(Euploea_core_core)_underside.jpg) with (according to Wikipedia) 15 subspecies identified, prevalent in south Asia, and Australia - the adult is distasteful to birds as the caterpillar feeds on latex-bearing plants.

The exact mixture of colours in the caterpillar stage will depend on the diet.

It has a neat trick when attacked, it shams death and oozes a sticky fluid which when ingested by birds make them vomit they find it so distasteful. The butterfly will then "miraculously recover" and fly off, with the bird having learned to avoid that type.

<sup>Unable to post images at the moment, so put links instead.</sup>